# Most wp_nav_menu parameters ignored

Tags: themes, customization, navigation, core, sandbox

I'm trying to get a text-based navigation menu for the footer of my site. I'm using the `wp_nav_menu()` parameters as directed by [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Removing_the_ul_wrap). He're a snippet of code (in `footer.php`):

```
<div id="footer">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('depth'=>1, 'after'=>'<span class="sep">|</span>')); ?><br />
    <div id="address">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contactInfo">
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- #footer -->
```

So, my goal is to make the menu look like `Home | About | MorePages` with only the root-level pages included.

### The problem:

The `after` parameter is ignored! If I try `before` and `items_wrap`, along with other parameters, they are also ignored. I've been able to get `after_link` and `before_link` to work, as well as `depth`.

I've tried escaping things and not passing HTML, but neither helps.

I'm building based on the Sandbox theme, but `nav-menu-template.php` and `nav-menu.php` appear unchanged from the WP core.

**How can I get these custom parameters to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your not being able to use `before` and `after` is because when you're calling [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) with a default fallback of [`wp_page_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu), which does not have a `before` and `after` arguments.

Refer to line 171: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L137

Apparently the menu you are trying to get does not exist (has no items) the `!$menu` is `true`. Make sure you have created a menu in `Appearance > Menus` and set it to a default one, or query for an existing one, or customize the fallback function, otherwise `wp_page_menu` will be called, simply listing all the pages.